# How can I insert an associative array into sql?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative-array

This is my array:

```
[abominado] => Array
    (
        [0] => r├⌐probo
        [1] => r├⌐probo
        [2] => abominado
        [3] => banido
        [4] => condenado
        [5] => detestado
        [6] => odiado
        [7] => precito
        [8] => renegado
        [9] => repudiado
    )

[abominar] => Array
    (
        [0] => repelir
        [1] => repelir
        [2] => abominar
        [3] => afastar
        [4] => afugentar
        [5] => arredar
        [6] => desalojar
        [7] => desviar
        [8] => detestar
        [9] => empuxar
        [10] => escorra├ºar
        [11] => espinafrar
        [12] => execrar
        [13] => exercer
        [14] => expulsar
        [15] => grimpar
        [16] => impugnar
        [17] => odiar
        [18] => rebater
        [19] => recha├ºar
        [20] => recusar
        [21] => rejeitar
        [22] => relegar
        [23] => repudiar
    )
```

how can I insert it into sql ?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($abominado as $key=>$str)
{
    $string .= "$key:$str\n";
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO strings VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($string)."')");
```

Comment: spraff this is case when his array is static

Comment: Oh, thing is, these are just an example, there are 37k words, I should make another foreach ?

Comment: @andré yep, do it as you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize` to cast it to string and `unserialize` when you get it

Answer (score 0):

First, these arrays happen to be sequential.

Second, in a SQL table, any column can be used as a search criteria, so just insert the data directly and set up an index on any searchable column.